# There is a way to check if a folder is a system folder?

Tags: java, android, system, directory

I want to make an Android app which does something with folders and I'm going to allow my app to delete some folders. 
I want not to allow my app to delete system folders or folders used by another apps so I'm asking if there is a way to figure out by code if a folder is a system folder or if it's used by another apps so I'm gonna discard these folders, there is a way? Because if I delete these folders I think that can make the O.S. unstable.

Comment: You won't have permission to delete those without root anyway.

Comment: This type of app is pretty much a virus, and Linux/Android have protections in place to keep these kinds of operations from happening. So you're out of luck on that one.

Comment: @drschultz it's kinda an app for deleting empty folders! I don't want to make a virus lol

Comment: No; you'll get an error if you try.

Comment: @SLaks ok, thanks! I want to explaing again that I don't want to make a virus or something like that

Comment: @Omar - I wasn't accusing you of trying to make a virus, lol. My point was, those types of operations are things that a virus would love to do...dig into your system and start modifying your files...and Linux/Android have protections in place to prevent that kind of behavior without the proper permissions.